# 12 count versus 24 count cupcake pan

Tags: cupcakes

I have a commercial oven, 2 to be exact,  each one can hold 10 dozen standard size cupcakes at one time.  My question is this, would I be better off using the regular 12 count muffin pans or going with the 24 count muffin pans?  Do they still bake evenly regardless of which one used?  thank you!

Comment: How many cupcakes are you trying to bake at one time?

Answer (score 3):

You're probably better off going with the bigger pans. A more influential factor than "how evenly the pan cooks the muffins" will probably be the time you're taking things in and out of the oven. So, if you have to remove ten, rather than just five pans (and/or to rotate them), you may get some unevenness.